# C: trouble displaying linked list from a text file

Tags: c, linked-list

So i'm having trouble in displaying the linked list from a txt file onto the screen.
here my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

struct sv
{
    char name[20];
    int age;
    char phonenum[15];
    struct sv *next;
};typedef struct sv SV;

struct data
{
    char name[20];
    int age;
    char phonenum[15];
};typedef struct data DATA;

SV *head = NULL;

void show(SV *r)
{
    r = head;
    int count = 0;

    if( r==NULL )
    {
        return;
    }
    while (r!=NULL)
    {
        if (count++ != 10)
        {
            printf("%s %d %s",r->name,r->age,r->phonenum);
        }
        else 
        {
            printf("%s %d %s",r->name,r->age,r->phonenum);
            count = 0;
        }

        r = r->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void add(DATA &a)
{
    SV *p,*right;
    p = (SV*)malloc(sizeof(*p));

    p->next = NULL;

    right = head;
    if (right==NULL)
    {
        head=p;
    }
    else
    {
        while(right->next != NULL)
            right=right->next;

        right->next = p;
    }
}

void appendFile()
{
    char line[100];
    char *token;
    char s[] = " ";
    DATA d;
    FILE *f = fopen("C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\mt.txt","r");

    while (fgets(line,sizeof(line),f)!=NULL)
    {
        token = strtok(line,s);

        while ( token != NULL )
        {
            printf( " %s\n", token );
            sscanf(token, "%s %d %s", d.name,d.age,d.phonenum);
            add(d);

            token = strtok(NULL,s);
            printf(" Token =%p \n", token);
        }
    }
    printf("DONE!");
    show(head);

}

int main()
{
    appendFile();
    show(head);
    return 0;
}
```

When i use the show() function it didnt display the right data that the function appendFile() read in from the txt file that i created
Heres the data in txt file:

```
HuongLeNguyen 19 0934908500
DoTanTruongSanh 19 0934908511
```

And this is what the function show() display:

```
╨xÜ 1330860869 RS=8╨xÜ 1551069797 ADMIN\OneDrive╨xÜ 1886405421 \MinGW64\bin;C:\ Ü╨xÜ 1986095708 apath;C:\WINDOWS`Ü╨xÜ 977484653 \WINDOWS\System3áÜ╨xÜ 1884249138 enSSH\;C:\Progra
╨xÜ 1330860869 RS=8╨xÜ 1551069797 ADMIN\OneDrive╨xÜ 1886405421 \MinGW64\bin;C:\ Ü╨xÜ 1986095708 apath;C:\WINDOWS`Ü╨xÜ 977484653 \WINDOWS\System3áÜ╨xÜ 1884249138 enSSH\;C:\Progra
```

Can someone help me about this problem.I would be very grateful if anyone could help!!

Comment: `void add(DATA &a) {` is invalid in C. Isn't this code C++?

Comment: What is the contents of the file `C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\mt.txt`? Is the contents tab-separated? Also note that the 4th argument of `sscanf(token, "%s %d %s", d.name,d.age,d.phonenum);` looks weird.

Comment: @MikeCAT the content is down below and what 4th argument? i only see 3

Comment: @MikeCAT the void add(DATA &a) was my mistake just ignore the 'DATA &a'

Comment: I see the contents. The 4th argument is `d.age`. `token` is 1st, `"%s %d %s"` is 2nd, `d.name` is 3rd and `d.phonenum` is 5th.

Comment: @MikeCAT i see, can you explain what weird about it.

Comment: `int` is passed while `int*` is expected. It may cause Segmentation Fault if the value is read. Actually it may not triggered because only one token cut by `strtok()` is passed there, so the value to read may not exist.

Comment: thank you a lot, so can you show me how to fix it please

Comment: If `char s[] = " ";` and `token = strtok(line,s);`, then you won't be able to `sscanf(token, "%s %d %s", d.name,d.age,d.phonenum);` because your `token` will be one of `HuongLeNguyen` or `19` or `0934908500` (not all 3). You need `sscanf(line, ...` and forget `strtok` altogether -- that is what `sscanf` is doing for you.

Comment: The`add` function do not use data from `a`. It should copy it into `p`

Comment: OT: regarding: `p = (SV*)malloc(sizeof(*p));`  1) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code and is error prone.  Suggest removing that cast.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call: `perror( "malloc failed" );` to output both your error message 'malloc failed' and the text reason the system thinks the function failed

Comment: OT: when calling and of the `scanf()` family of functions, the parameters much be the address of the variable. so (other than for arrays) the variable name must be prefixed with `&`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regarding:

```
p = (SV*)malloc(sizeof(*p));

p->next = NULL;

right = head;
if (right==NULL)
{
    head=p;
}
```

the data fields from the passed parameter `a` are never copied into the allocated memory.  So when trying to print out that memory, the code is trying to print uninitialized fields.

regarding:

```
 sscanf(token, "%s %d %s", d.name,d.age,d.phonenum);
```

1. when using the `%s` input format conversion specifier, need to always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input field because that specifier always appends a NUL byte to the input.  This also avoids any possibility of a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior
2. the parameter `d.age` is NOT an array, so need to specify the address, not the contents.  Suggest:

   sscanf( token, "%s %d %s", d.name, &d.age,d.phonenum );

However, the call to `strtok()` will stop and drop a NUL byte after `name` which will have some bad effects on the call to `sscanf()`.   Suggest eliminating the `token` and the call to `strtok()` and use something similar to:

```
if( sscanf( line, "%s %d %s", d.name, &d.age, d.phonenum ) != 3)
{
    fprintf( stderr, "failed to extract name, age, phonenum from input line\n" );  
    fclose( f );
    // need to also pass all allocated memory to `free()` at this failure point
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```

then if the call to `sscanf()` was successful, then use `strcpy` for the two character arrays: `name` and `phonenum` and copy them from the `d` struct to the allocated memory.  Then simply assign the `age` field of the `d` struct to the allocated memory